# Observe element innerHTML changes wiht jQuery.text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, bind

I need to remove a class from an `a` element when another piece of code calls `.text('string')` on it. I cannot edit this other piece of code:

```
function WPSetAsThumbnail(id, nonce){
    var $link = jQuery('a#wp-post-thumbnail-' + id);

    // this is where it's first called
    $link.text( setPostThumbnailL10n.saving );
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {
        action:"set-post-thumbnail", post_id: post_id, thumbnail_id: id, _ajax_nonce: nonce, cookie: encodeURIComponent(document.cookie)
    }, function(str){
        var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top;
        $link.text( setPostThumbnailL10n.setThumbnail );
        if ( str == '0' ) {
            alert( setPostThumbnailL10n.error );
        } else {
            jQuery('a.wp-post-thumbnail').show();
            $link.text( setPostThumbnailL10n.done );
            $link.fadeOut( 2000 );
            win.WPSetThumbnailID(id);
            win.WPSetThumbnailHTML(str);
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Thanks so much for bearing with me even if this is such a noob question.

Comment: It's not a noob question, and the answer isn't that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), but be aware that they're deprecated.
2. Pull the DOM seek for changes.

The second option example:

```
var $element = $("#elementId");
var lastText = $element.text();
function checkForChanges()
{
    var currText = $element.text();
    if (currText !== lastText)
    {
        alert('xxx');
        lastText = currText;
    }
}

var id = setInterval(checkForChanges, 500);
```

Comment: kk, workin on this.. any chance to do this without intervals? :D

Comment: @AnaBan. `mutation events` which might be even worse... depends on the DOM. If you could change the other code...